# Illegal constructor using useSelector from react-redux lib?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

Why do I get this error?

> TypeError: Illegal constructor

Beow is my store.js file:

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

import formReducer from './features/form/form'
import modalReducer from './features/modal-status/modal'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  modal: modalReducer,
  process: formReducer
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default function createStore() {
  let store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    devTools: true
  })
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

Below is my form reducer code:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'process',
  initialState: {
    type: 'UNKNOWN',
    isLogined: false,
    username: null,
    clientId: null,
    avatarUri: null
  },
  reducers: {
    process(state, action) {
      if(action.payload.type == 'LOGIN') {
        if('username' in action.payload && 'clientId' in action.payload && 'avatarUri' in action.payload) {
          return {
            ...state,
            type: 'LOGIN',
            isLogined: action.payload.isLogined,
            username: action.payload['username'],
            clientId: action.payload['clientId'],
            avatarUri: action.payload['avatarUri'],
          }
        }
      } else {
        return state
      }
    }
  }
})

export const { process } = formSlice.actions
export default formSlice.reducer
```

And in react component I used useSelector hook like below:

```
  const isLogin = useSelector(state => state.process.isLogined)
```

Comment: As always, the *entire* stack trace is relevant. Filter out private file paths if you have to.

Comment: ah i see 
```
PersistGate.Component.setState
node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js (365:0)
eval
node_modules\redux-persist\es\integration\react.js (61:0)
Object.dispatch
node_modules\redux\es\redux.js (297:0)
Object.rehydrate
node_modules\redux-persist\es\persistStore.js (79:0)
_rehydrate
node_modules\redux-persist\es\persistReducer.js (61:0)
eval
node_modules\redux-persist\es\persistReducer.js (90:0)
```
when i'm tracing stack i see maybe it's about redux-persist failure @JonJaques

Comment: @JonJaques but i dont know how to fix it :)

Comment: Totes - but then, you gotta eliminate things until your app code works.

Your redux code looks right, my suggestion would be to eliminate the redux-persist code until the basic example works.

Comment: If you construct the store like so—
```
let store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    devTools: true
  })
```

and it works, then you know the problem is in the persist-store plugin - that module looks like it's in a lot of flux. I would look at what functionality it's giving me and based on the readme, probably not use it, personally...

Comment: @JonJaques i have solved the problem and i posted the solution here: [link](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/1352) and i cannot remove redux-persist lib because i need some state still remain after i reload the page and if you dont cache store it will not remain state when you reload the page :)